# PHP : $token changing his value when saved into a cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I'm trying to setting up a connection cookie, but I'm running some troubles.

```
$token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$token = bin2hex($token);
setcookie('token', $token, time() + 14*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
```

The problem is that $token change his value just in the cookie:

```
$token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
$token = bin2hex($token);
echo $token; //939ec30ae568e2c8ee192a488cb6e646
setcookie('token', $token, time() + 14*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
echo $_COOKIE['token']; //4254ffefa72a856f40540d2bf879546a
echo $token; //939ec30ae568e2c8ee192a488cb6e646
```

I bet it's a silly problem, but I can't find any reason why this var is doing this.

(And since I have this issue, I can't use it for connection : the value in the database is not the same)

Answer (score 2):

It's not changing it, it's setting it but you can't see the value of $_COOKIE until the page refreshes.

The reason you think it's changing it is because it's setting the cookie from the previous page load each time.

You need to check if the cookie exists, if it doesn't, then set it.

```php
if (!isset($_COOKIE["token"])){
    $token = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $token = bin2hex($token);
    setcookie('token', $token, time() + 14*24*3600, null, null, false, true);
} else {
    echo $_COOKIE['token'];
}
```

In your example, when you refresh the page it will generate a new cookie, but echo $_COOKIE['token'] will display 939ec30ae568e2c8ee192a488cb6e646

Comment: Actualy, I have the test earlyer in the code, I'm inside a connection function.

The main problem is that the token value get to be different in the cookie and the database.

One it's created, the cookie's value doesn't change over refreshing... but doesn't match the database.

Comment: @Oonae The key point remains: `$_COOKIE` reflects the value _the browser sent at the beginning of this request_, it is not updated by a call to `setcookie`. You need a functoin with an `if` statement like shown in this answer, and `return $token` or `return $_COOKIE['token']`; then save the result of that function to your database, rather than directly looking at `$_COOKIE['token']`.